# Gnuplot factorial calculation output

Tags: function, recursion, floating-point, gnuplot, factorial

I wanted to test a recursive function in gnuplot.
The following is the function

`factorial(n)= ((n==1?sprintf("1"):sprintf("%f",n*factorial(n-1))))`

when factorial(100) tested, it looks fine

`93326215443944102188325606108575267240944254854960571509166910400407995064242937148632694030450512898042989296944474898258737204311236641477561877016501813248.000000`

to make the number a integer, i changed sprintf like that

`factorial(n)= ((n==1?sprintf("1"):sprintf("%d",n*factorial(n-1))))`

But, the result is strange ; it seemed to be out of range on integer size?

`-2147483648`

So i changed the function on real number type without no number below floating point

`factorial(n)= ((n==1?sprintf("1"):sprintf("%.0f",n*factorial(n-1))))`

But, the result is more strange,

`-75703234367175440481992733883343393025021587121454605713387911182978138051561570016048371488788270318477285688499861254195149884149214115360733197762560`

Could u explain what it is?
Thanks,

Comment: Even without the background Ethan explained, your `factorial(100)` doesn't look fine! Since you are multiplying the numbers from 1 to 100, the last digits of the result should be a lot of zeros (I would guess at least 20), but definitely not `...13248`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest integer that can be represented in 32 bits is 2147483647.
So a 32-bit integer (gnuplot through version 5.2) runs out of bits between 12! and 13!

A 64-bit integer (gnuplot 5.4) runs out of bits between 20! and 21!

If you use double precision floating point arithmetic it can hold larger numbers, but the number of bits still limits the precision.  64-bit floating point has only ~53 bits of precision, so the largest exact factorial it can represent is actually smaller than can be handled by a 64-bit integer.

Note that all of your example gnuplot code uses integer arithmetic if n is an integer.  Changing to a floating point format for printing doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your final goal is... But just for fun and feasibility, you *can* calculate `Factorial(100)` with gnuplot.
However, you will get the result as a string. I haven't tested what the limits for the arguments `a` and `d` would be. For `a` it would be maximum string length and for `d` probably the integer limit (32 bit or 64 bit).

**Code:**

```
### factorial for large numbers (output as string!)
reset session

# a: integer number string 
# d: integer number   
Multiply(a,d) = (_u=0, _tmp='', _n=strlen(a), sum [_i=1:_n] (_j=_n-_i+1, \
           _m1=a[_j:_j]*d, _d1=(_m1+_u)%10, _u=(_m1+_u)/10, \
           _tmp=sprintf("%d%s",_d1,_tmp),0), _u ? sprintf("%d%s",_u,_tmp) : _tmp)

Factorial(n) = (_tmp="1", sum [_j=1:n] ( _tmp=Multiply(_tmp,_j), 0), _tmp)

print Factorial(100)
### end of code
```

**Result: 100!** (actually, 24 zeros at the end)

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```